# Достать параметры/значения Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit

Есть такой рабочий блок кода для retrofit2

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Retrofit retrofit =  new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseSpiceService.URL_SITE+"/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    ServerConnectionService scs = retrofit.create(ServerConnectionService.class);

    baseResponse = scs.updateMe1(map, body).execute().body();
    Log.e("UpdateMeRequest", "loadDataFromNetwork: baseResponse code = " +baseResponse.getCode() );
    Log.e("UpdateMeRequest", "loadDataFromNetwork: baseResponse message = " +baseResponse.getMessage() );
```

**Как мне внедрить в него обработку статуса 404 от сервера и оттуда же код сообщения и само сообщение?**

Отдельно вызывал тело ошибки с помощью

```
String s = scs.updateMe1(map, body).execute.errorBody();
```

потом уже эту строку в JsonObject и доставал по ключам. Но тогда при отсутствии статуса 404 от сервера такой код не выполнялся.

Как мне совместить мой блок кода и обработку ошибки одним потоком?

И было бы замечательно, если бы я мог обращаться к статус кодам сервера и html адресу, который обычно хранится в переменной retrofit - после запуска потока

**Интерфейс такой:**

```
@Multipart
@retrofit2.http.POST("v1/me")
Call<BaseResponse> updateMe1(@retrofit2.http.QueryMap Map<String, String> stringMap, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

Comment: По идее должно быть как-то так: `Responce<PespoceBody> response = scs.updateMe1(map, body).execute()` и далее смотреть что за респонс: `if(response.isSuccessful()){respose.body();} else {response.errorBody()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно я вместо выполнения в том же потоке `.execute().body()` пользуюсь callback-ом `.enqueue(mCallback)`, чтобы вызывать загрузку из UI потока, и не бывает нужды самостоятельно определять, какой ответ пришел.

Вроде в Вашем случае пример был бы таким:

```
scs.updateMe1(map, body).enqueue(new Callback<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
                if (response.body() == null) {
                    // тут ловятся такие ошибки, как 404 и 500
                } else {
                    // тут объект класса <T> успешно создался
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
                // тут ловятся непредвиденные исключения,
                // появившиеся во время создания запроса или обработки ответа
            }
        }
```

В данном примере класс `<T>` - это класс того объекта, который вы ожидаете в успешном ответе, в Вашем случае это `BaseResponse`.

Если всё таки есть необходимость запускать синхронную загрузку в том же потоке, то данное действо выглядело бы вот так:

```
    Response response = scs.updateMe1(map, body).execute();
    int code = response.code(); // статус код сервера

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        baseRespose = response.body();
    } else {
        Log.e("UpdateMeRequest", "HTTP status code = " + code );
    }
```

ну и все это дело у Вас уже наверняка обёрнуто в try-catch на случай непредвиденных ситуаций.

Comment: enqueue - асинхронный поток, а execute синхронный. То есть, с enqueue  не будет последовательности. Верно же? А мне нужно обрабатывать результат запроса синхронно, получается нужен execute . Если мои суждения не верны, сообщите

Comment: Всё верно, просто из отрывка не видно причины такого подхода. Почему бы не сделать отдельный класс, который из UI потока запускает асинхронно загрузчик :)

Comment: у меня проект и с retrofit1 и с retrofit2, причём отдельный класс, который из UI потока запускает синхронно загрузчик уже есть но на retrofit1, я к этому дойду, но не сегодня =)

Comment: ну тогда обновил ответ)

Comment: добавил интерфейс в вопрос. Это изменит Ваш код для меня, с моим интерфейсом?

Comment: только добавил строку про класс ответа в асинхронной загрузке, сможете потом заменить generic <T> на класс BaseResponse :)